# Adding validates_uniqueness_of to a model fails functional tests

Tags: unit-testing, validation, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

Trying to make a simple application in rails 3.

If I create a team model with `rails g scaffold team name:string && rake db:migrate`, then run `rake`, I get success from the prebuilt tests.

If I simply add `validates_uniqueness_of :name` to the team model. The functional tests fail with

```
  1) Failure:
test_should_create_team(TeamsControllerTest) [/test/functional/teams_controller_test.rb:20]:
"Team.count" didn't change by 1.
<3> expected but was
<2>.
```

I modified tests/fixtures/teams.yml to look like this:

```
one:
    name: MyString
two:
    name: MyString2
```

The test still fails.

It can't get much more basic than this; what have I missed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixtures basically represent model instances that are in the database.

If you look at the top of test/functional/teams_controller_test.rb you'll see

```
setup do
  @team = teams(:one)
end
```

and then in your failing functional test you'll have

```
post :create, :team => @team.attributes
```

This is what's happening: you're trying to create a new team with the same attributes as "the team fixture named :one". Since both would have the same name (since they have the exact same attributes), the uniqueness validation is failing.

Try replacing your setup block with this

```
setup do
  @team = teams(:one)
  @team.name = 'unique name'
end
```

Now you'll be creating a new team with the name 'unique name' (which isn't in the database according to the fixtures), and your test will pass.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I'm not sure on the real purpose of the fixtures but this helps so much. Do you know how bad I felt doing a `git rm -r test` ?

Comment: Well, now you're on your way to tested code ;-). The purpose fixtures have is a "base scenario" for your database: you know what is in the database, so you can predict what should happen when you add/create a model and compare the actual results with asserts. But fixtures have their own set of problems, and you might want to looking into defining the contents of your database in your test with factories (such as Factory Girl).